# How to maintain version of file

Tags: database, version-control, fileversioninfo

I want to develop a document maintenance system. The problem I am facing is how to maintain version of a file? I have a one method: i.e. to create a history folder and if someone wants to update a file, he will do some changes and upload it again. Upon uploading the file I will keep a separate history folder for every file and add the updated version of the file. Please suggest me if anyone have solution. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: in a document maintenance system you would like to keep each version of a document so ideally a database can be used to keep the different versions of the document, with a db it is easy to keep track of history and versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of capable version control systems available, most with good APIs. Think of them as databases for files.